# change the size of writeablebitmap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I was wondering if it was possible to change the size of a WriteableBitmap in WP7. I have noticed that the default size is 640x480, and my windows phone application is in Portrait mode, so I would like the height of my writeablebitmap (which I am using to overylay a live grayscale camera image) could be increased accordingly (while ofcourse keeping the same aspect ratio). I have not been able to find anything regarding this anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Why not instead create a bitmap of the desired size [using the relevant constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901609%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: I have attempted to create a writeablebitmap of the same aspect ratio as the default (4:3) but a different size, except this does not work and errors occur. Do you have a quick sample of how to properly do this. My application is in portrait mode, so I have tried calling the screens height in code behind, then calculating the width accordingly (the sides of the width section will be cut so that the image will not be stretched).